# Lifespan of Getstream feed cursors

Tags: getstream-io

With Getstream, what's the lifespan of a feed cursor (activity ID)? I'm writing an iOS app where the activities are persisted to Core Data for offline viewing. I was thinking of using the persisted activity IDs in conjunction with the Stream `id_lt` pagination param to sync my Core Data DB with updates from my server (which forwards requests to Stream). For how long can an activity ID be used as a pagination cursor?

It also appears that an activity ID can be used for pagination even after the activity of said ID has been removed. Is this behavior guaranteed, and if so, for how long? Not sure if it's working for me only because the activity ID remains available until a nightly cleanup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The activity ID will not invalidate at any point. Thus you can use them as long as the activity isn't deleted. For pagination the activity ID can be used even if the activity is deleted.